# AngularJS: ng-options "non-choice" is not the top

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I made my select tag directive of the private use

**template html**

```
<div>
  <select ng-model="model" ng-options="item as item[labelName] for item in array">
    <option ng-if="!!hasTop" value="">non choice</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

"array" is return value of $recource.query

With "non choice" in the top, I want to have.
ex

```
  Select
    +-"non choice"
    +-option a
    +-option b
```

but, not work

```
  Select
    +-option a
    +-option b
    +-"non choice"
```

help me.

**Additional requirements**

It became the top when I deleted ng-if. 
but. In this directive, I want to control display of "non choice" with an attribute
Is there a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, You need to set an empty options at the top. In that case use like below

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="item as item[labelName] for item in array">
    <option value="">non choice</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.
It became the top when I deleted ng-if.
but. In this directive, I want to control display of "non choice" with an attribute.
Is there a good idea?

Comment: I'm sorry.
I have contributed it on the way.
I updated comment

Comment: ng-show is work! but, I do not want to put the element which is unnecessary for DOM if possible.;(

Comment: dayo, I understand. But the way I read the ngOptions code, it looks for your emptyOption tag, if it finds it, it inserts it. It will only insert one. So, as I see it, you have 3 choices: 1) write your own ngOptions directive. 2) use ng-if or ng-switch on the select itself (so have two versions of the select, one with the empty option, one without). or 3) use ng-show. I think #3 is easiest

Comment: Thank you, o4ohel. I thought about 2), too.I think most because influence is big, 1) intends to make 2)